# how to upload/write/read files from smart card? is there any free/paid software?

Tags: smartcard, client-certificates, smartcard-reader

I'm trying to write/upload CA certificates to a smart card, for enabling smart card authentication But I'm unable to connect to the card using omnikey3021 smart card reader. awp authentic manager software shows 'the smart card is not recognized'. Drivers of smart card are already installed. is there any other software other than authentic manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately smart cards do typically not achieve interoperability without pressure from a strong specification. So even while *CREATE FILE* is standardized in ISO 7816-9, the OS of different manufacturers may require additional data objects or show some deviations.

If the card is not blank, but already contains something, the process to achieve access rights to enable writing additional stuff is so variable, that I'm not aware of a general-purpose / multi-supplier tool. The tools typically end on the level of APDUs and you have to take care of everything beyond that by yourself.